# Linq To Twitter - User search on name fails when the name contains symbols

Tags: c#, twitter, linq-to-twitter

I'm trying to add a feature to my application that searches a Twitter user's name (not screen name) and returns a list of all users found. It all works fine until I try to search a name with only symbols.

I've changed my name on Twitter to "!£$", and when I try to search for it I get a TwitterQueryException with the message "Could not authenticate you". If I try to URL encode the name I get a TwitterQueryException with the message "Missing or invalid url parameter".

Here's my query (which works fine for non symbol names):

```
var users = (from user in twitter.User
                where user.Type == UserType.Search &&
                user.Query == name &&
                user.Name == name
                select user).ToList();
```

I've tried using BuildUrlHelper.UrlEncode(name), Uri.EscapeUriString(name) and HttpUtility.UrlEncode, but I still get the same error.

I'm using version 2.1.11

Comment: Can you try adding something like "-test" at the beginning of your search query?

Comment: You mean [string name = "-test";]? Same error.

Comment: You have to add it at the beginning of the string containing your username. So for example "-test BillGates".

Comment: "-test" gives me "Missing or invalid url parameter". "-test !£$" gives me "Could not authenticate you". But when I search for any normal name without symbols I get results.

Comment: Isn't there another way you can search for a specific user? I remember I did this once too, but I just used `Uri.EscapeuriString` which worked fine (back then).

Comment: I've tried BuildUrlHelper.UrlEncode, Uri.EscapeUriString, HttpUtility.UrlEncode, all with the same result

Comment: Strange, do you need to select on both Query and Name property? Their documentation says you can just use the Query property, but I don't know if its the screenname or username (https://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Searching%20for%20Users&referringTitle=Getting%20User%20Information).

Comment: Query is the only required property, but as far as I know if used alone it'll search ScreenNames, names, Descriptions, etc. Name just narrows down the search. I've tried removing the Name field and I get the same result.

Comment: Okay, then I wouldn't know what to do. You should reach out to the codeplex page and ask for help there. I think its a bug.

Comment: Thought I did that on Monday, but just realised I posted it under Discussions, not Issues, just reposted, some votes might help =): https://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/workitem/32637

Comment: Hehe, I've upvoted your issue. Good luck solving it.